Number Theory - A problem about reduced residue system and congruence
Let $a$ be an integer and $p$ be a prime. Consider the set $E = \{ av-u : 0 \leq u < \sqrt{p}, 0 \leq v < \sqrt{p} \}$. So are all elements of $E$ distinct from each other? Do we have $|E| = (\lfloor \sqrt{p} \rfloor+1)^2 > p$? But what if $E$ contains duplicate elements?
Furthermore, by the Pigeonhole principle, do we have that there exists two different combinations of $u,v$: $\{ u_1, v_1 \}$ and $\{ u_2, v_2 \}$ such that
$$
a v_1 - u_1 \equiv a v_2 - u_2 \pmod{p}
$$
If so, why is this true?

The multi-set E has $(\lfloor \sqrt{p} \rfloor+1)^2 > p $ elements. Since there are only $p$ residues, by PHP, 2 elements of E must have the same residue, which gives us $av_1  - u_1 \equiv av_2 - u_2 \pmod{p}$.

What if $a \mid \lfloor \sqrt p \rfloor -1?$

@CalvinLin Oh, now I understand it! Thank you so much!

@CalvinLin And do we have that at least one of $v_1 \neq v_2$ and $u_1 \neq u_2$ is true?

Yes. The 2 elements of $E$ are distinct, which means that $ (v_1, u_1) \neq (v_2, u_2)$, which means at least one of statements must hold.

@CalvinLin So why are they distinct? Why can't they just be the same?

Because that's what PHP says. It is trivial that "there is 1 pigeon in a hole". PHP says that "there are 2 pigeons, not the same ones, that are in a hole".

But $E$ is a multiset, which means its elements can repeat. So how can we know that the two elements chosen for the congruence are different?

@CalvinLin Or can we show that $E$ is not a multiset? I know how the principle works. E.g. if a set has 4 different numbers, then at least 2 of them must be congruent mod 3.

@CalvinLin And actually, I met this while reading the proof of a theorem, and in that proof, there is also a condition: $a^2 \equiv -3 \pmod{p}$. I'm not sure if this guarantees that elements of $E$ are distinct.

The elements $(v_1, u_1), (v_2, u_2)$ are distinct. They might have the same evaluation of $av_1-u_1 = av_2 - u_2$ as integers. $\quad$ To me, you seem to be tripping yourself up over the definitions/terminology. As such, I would recommend looking at this tomorrow with fresh eyes.

@CalvinLin Oh I understand it now. Thank you very much!

@CalvinLin Here is what I think: I can think of a set ${ (u,v) : 0 \leq u < \sqrt{p}, 0 \leq v < \sqrt{p} }$. All elements of this set are distinct, and I can think of a bijection between this set and E. And a set with $n$ integers (not necessarily distinct) must contain two numbers mod $n-1$. These give the result. Is that correct?

@helloworld142857 Yup. Looks good to me.

@CalvinLin Ok, thank you so much!
